# how to decode utf-8 string to actual text?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter with php 5.6 and mysql db for this specific purpose. I want to store strings from different languages to database and retrieve them later. 
Problem I am facing here is when I am trying to grab the value, instead of giving out exact text, it shows something in the following format.

> %E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87

Here's some test code

```
function charset($get = NULL){
   $direct = "नमस्ते";

$this->load->database();    
  if($get != NULL){
        $this->db->insert('test', array("name"=>"get", "value"=>$get));
        $this->db->insert('test', array("name"=>"direct", "value"=>$direct));
    }
    $results = $this->db->get('test')->result_array();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);

}
```

and Here are the results

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [name] => get
        [value] => %E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 17
        [name] => direct
        [value] => नमस्ते
    )


)
```

how would you get (or convert) the exact word instead of ut8 encoded string?

Comment: `नमस्ते` is the UTF8 encoded string. `%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87` is the URL-encoded UTF8 string. You're probably looking for [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode).

Comment: This is just [`urlencode()`d](http://php.net/urlencode), not quite UTF-8 yet. You should investigate how it ended up in `$get` or the database like that.

Comment: thankyou mario and marekful! thing is how do I covert this string back to actual word?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code like below and it is returning value proper:

```
$variable = '%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87';
echo urldecode($variable);
```

Hope I understood your code properly.

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple things at play here

**MySQL**

In MySQL you need to configure the connection/client to use it:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

In PHP it might be something similar to this:

```
$this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

**HTML**

When outputting to HTML, you'll also have to tell the client (browser) what data you're passing:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And/or in your HTML body:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Please explain that further. How does all these affect a urlencoded string?